# Yield and yield from - can you combine them?

Tags: python

Just found out about the `yield from` construct, which to my idea is somewhat like a reversed `yield`, instead of getting an object out of a generator, you insert/ send an object to a generator. Like:

```
def foo():
    while True:
        x = (yield)
        print(f'{x=}')

f = foo()
f.send(None)
for i in range(4):
    f.send(i)
```

yields:

```
x=0
x=1
x=2
x=3
```

So then I wondered if you can combine the two.

```
def foo():
    while True:
        x = (yield)
        print(f'{x=}')
        yield x + 1000

f = foo()
f.send(None)
for i in range(4):
    print(f'y={f.send(i)}')
```

Then I would expect

```
x=0
y=1000
x=1
y=1001
x=2
y=1002
x=3
y=1003
```

but I get

```
x=0
y=1000
y=None
x=2
y=1002
y=None
```

Anyone can explain this?

Comment: Note `f'{x=}'` only works in Python 3.8+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd 'combine the two', it's useful to think of `yield` as a **single** point of sending values out, and then accepting values in from outside. That way, you might appreciate why you don't get a line printing out "x=" every alternate line and get `None`s every third line in your output. This is because *the control comes out of `foo(..)`* two times every loop in the `while` block.

Here's the fixed version of your code:

```
def foo():
    x = 0
    while True:
        x = (yield x + 1000)
        print(f'{x=}')

f = foo()
f.send(None)
for i in range(4):
    print(f'y={f.send(i)}')
```

Comment: Understood. The one yield in foo() performs both functions, getting the value and sending the value. Running it through a debugger I can see what is happening. The function foo first seems to get the value from i and prints it, then it goes to the line x = yield(x + 1000) and returns to the loop with the value x + 1000. If I add the line x = x * 2 before the print the result is x=0, y=1000, x=2, y=1002, x=4, y=1004, x=6, y=1006.